# What is the usage of material-ui useScrollTrigger with child target ref?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I am trying to use [material-ui's useScrollTrigger](https://material-ui.com/components/app-bar/#usescrolltrigger-options-trigger) with a target other than `window` like so:

```
export default props => {
    let contentRef = React.createRef();

    const scrollTrigger = useScrollTrigger({ target: contentRef.current });

    return (
        <React.Fragment>
            <CustomHeader shrink={scrollTrigger} />

            <div ref={contentRef}>
                {props.children}
            </div>
        </React.Fragment>
    );
};
```

This causes an error to be thrown because `contentRef.current` is null when `useScrollTrigger` is called. What is the proper usage of this utility with child elements as a target?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You were right, since the first time the component renders contentRef.current is null and so an error will be thrown.

We need two things a reference to the target Element, and a way to re-render so our scrollTrigger is calculated again. in other words we need a state.

The following code will work

```
export default props => {

    // please keep it undefined here to not make useScrollTrigger throw an error on first render 
    const [scrollTarget, setScrollTarget] = useState(undefined) 
    const scrollTrigger = useScrollTrigger({ target: scrollTarget });

    return (
        <React.Fragment>
            <CustomHeader shrink={scrollTrigger} />

            <div ref={node => {
                if (node) {
                    setScrollTarget(node);
                }
            }}>
                {props.children}
            </div>
        </React.Fragment>
    );
};
```

Comment: Perfect. Could you explain why this works and not my approach though? `scrollTarget` is still undefined when `useScrollTrigger` is called for the first time. I know that by using `useState` the function will get called again when the ref is no longer undefined, but shouldn't the first call still throw? Is there some magic by which the effect used internally knows that the state will change but not that the ref will be populated?

Comment: No there is no magic, the useScrollTrigger only works by the parameters it is given, that fact that it throws on null and not on undefined, is due to the way it's implemented. See here for more info https://material-ui.com/components/app-bar/#usescrolltrigger-options-trigger. undefined is usually better than null anyway, because undefined triggers the default parameter behaviour of functions while null does not do that. But anyway you need a state because the useRef hook does not cause a re-render when the ref callback is called ( unless you set a state yourself).

Comment: This code is not working for me. I want the scrollTrigger to be true if I scroll to a component/ node. I think the scrollTarget is not working. I checked the state and the state gets set with the div, but nothing change when I start scrolling. scrollTrigger is always false. Any idea?

Answer (score 4):

For you typescript users that feel left out, let me save you several hours of your lives figuring out the appropriate typing:

```
const [scrollTarget, setScrollTarget] = useState<Node | Window | undefined>()
const scrollTrigger = useScrollTrigger({ target: scrollTarget });
```

Answer (score 0):

If your scroll container is far far away from your child component in component three. You can give an `id` to your container and access it in the child.

```
 const trigger = useScrollTrigger({
    target: document.getElementById('mainContanier') as Node,
    disableHysteresis: true,
    // threshold: 100,
  });
```

Answer (score -2):

I would try something like this:

```
 const scrollTrigger = useScrollTrigger(() => {{ target: contentRef.current }});
```

Comment: This gives me an `Expected an assignment or function call and instead saw an expression  no-unused-expressions` error.