# MUI ScrollToTop component with the useScrollTrigger hook is not working

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, material-ui

I'm creating a `ScrollToTop` component by using MUI `useScrollTrigger` hook https://mui.com/material-ui/react-app-bar/#usescrolltrigger-options-trigger

Here is the sample code: https://codesandbox.io/s/stackoverlow-mui-usescrolltrigger-er9z4y

#### Problems

1. The `ScrollTop` component doesn't appear after scrolling some pixels even after scrolling to the bottom of the page.

Here is the screenshot.
The `ScrollToTop` component should appear around the area I marked.
As we could see that the `trigger` value from the `useScrollTrigger` hook returns a `false` value. It should return a `true` value if we scrolled the page.
[image]

2. If we uncomment the `ScrollToTop` component, the `ScrollToTop` component would appear. Then if we click the `ScrollToTop` component, the screen would not go to the top of the page.

Here is the screenshot.
[image]

#### Step To Reproduce

For problem 1:

1. Open the demo (codesandbox link) above.
2. Scroll to the bottom of the page.

For problem 2:

1. Open the demo (codesandbox link) above.
2. Comment only the `ScrollToTop` component.
3. Scroll to the bottom of the page.
4. Click the `ScrollToTop` component.

#### Expected conditions

1. For problem 1: the `ScrollTop` component appears after scrolling some pixels.
2. For problem 2: the `ScrollTop` component should bring the screen to the top of the page after being clicked.

Answer (score 0):

Problem here is useScrollTrigger use the by default window as target. But in your example your main content box is having the scroll. So you need to pass the reference of this main content box as target to the useScrollTrigger.

Refer - https://stackoverflow.com/a/56743659/1133582

Something as below -

```
const [scrollTarget, setScrollTarget] = React.useState<Node | undefined>(undefined);    

<Box ref={(node: Node) => {
          if (node) {
            setScrollTarget(node);
          }
        }} className={classes.pageOverflow}>
      <Toolbar id="back-to-top-anchor" className={classes.toolbar} />

      <Box className={classes.longBox}>Top Of the page</Box>

      <ScrollToTop scrollTarget={scrollTarget}>
        <Fab size="small" color="secondary" className={classes.scrollToTop}>
          <IconKeyboardDoubleArrowUpRounded />
        </Fab>
      </ScrollToTop>
    </Box>
```